# "Who wants ice-cream?" — Should I say "(not) I" or "(not) me"?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, personal-pronouns, grammatical-case, sentence-fragments

With the enthusiastic question of "Who wants ice-cream?", what is the more correct response?

> 1. (Not) I.
> 2. (Not) me.

Neither response is a sentence. The first response of "(not) I" sounds stuffy, like it should be followed with an indignant sniff. The second sounds like American idiom and acceptable for casual speech.

What do you say?

Comment: I scream, you scream, we all scream for ice cream.

Comment: Best of both worlds is usually best. Go with "not me", plus that cool indignant sniff thing.

Comment: It's easier to accept the offer: "I do."

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Generally speaking, in English, accusative (also known as “objective”) pronouns (like *me*) are the “default” form. That is, unless there is a specific syntactic rule requiring use of a different case, such as nominative (*I*), genitive (*my/mine*), or reflexive/intensive (*myself*), in English you use the accusative case.

In the syntactic context where a pronoun is not serving a role relative to an explicit verb, such as when it is the simple answer to a question, or if one is labeling something, such as a photo, accusative pronouns are standard. “Who wants to come?” “Me.” Nominative pronouns are impossible here—you cannot answer the question “Who wants to come?” with “I”, nor would anyone label a photo “I”.

This holds even if negated: “Who wants ice cream?” “Not me.”

If you want to use the highest register, most formal English, however, you should avoid the question of what case to use with pronouns standing alone, and use a complete sentence: “I do not want ice cream.”

Comment: you could also just say "I do" =).

Comment: No, it's correct to respond either "I" or "not I" to "who wants to come" or "who wants ice cream". Please don't tell me that I cannot answer these questions this way - I always would (and I am a native speaker), although I admit that it's less common than answering with "me" or "not me".  -1.

Comment: My understanding is that nonsentential utterances with nominative pronouns are ungrammatical hypercorrections—people consciously applying a grammatical "rule" they learned explicitly rather than through the natural process of language acquisition. Whether or not such utterances are grammatical I suppose is debatable, because so many people have been taught and sometimes use this "rule", such that artificial language instruction has interfered into the natural grammar of the language. I will stand by regarding it as ungrammatical, however.

Comment: This helps with 'nominative' and 'objective' : http://www.dailywritingtips.com/what-is-dative-case/

Comment: @nohat [Here’s a nice paper about this](http://roa.rutgers.edu/files/941-1207/941-FRAZIER-0-0.PDF) that I think you might like, complete with references.

Comment: @nohat What exactly is your source for the rule you stated in your answer? Which grammar authorities attest to this rule? Who gives it credence? Or is this your own ruling?

Comment: @TheWordsmith it's my own ruling based on my observations of how the English language works, but the paper tchrist links to, above, seems to agree.

Comment: @nohat That’s all well and good, but no canonical grammar authority seems to establish this as a rule. The paper provided by tchrist isn’t a grammar authority; it looks to be a research paper more than anything. Hence, I don’t think we can consider your “expert” opinion to be an official grammatical law, unless, of course, you can cite a proper authority.

Comment: @TheWordsmith lol @ "canonical grammar authority" and "official grammatical law". There's no such thing.

Comment: @nohat Do we not consider GMEU and the CMOS (among others) to be canonical grammar authorities? And ending a sentence with a period isn’t an official grammatical law? Perhaps “grammatical law” is a bit too much. Let’s call it a rule. You cannot deny that there are grammatical rules.

Comment: @TheWordsmith I would regard a research paper published by a linguist to be more authoritative than any book which just makes pronouncements about what is and is not grammatical from on high. I do not consider books published by self-appointed arbiters to be canonical or authoritative. There is no authority over the English language. Besides, to the best of my knowledge, those books don't comment on the grammaticality of non-sentential utterances.

Comment: @nohat I'm sorry you don't consider the Chicago Manual of Style or Garner's Modern English Usage to be authoritative. That's like saying the OED isn't the most trusted and most accredited dictionary. You are, I'm afraid,  in the minority. Any writer or professor considers those two authorities to be accredited ones. Linguistics and the rules of language—grammar—aren't inherently related, and thus a linguist has no more authoritativeness than a grammar; indeed, they have less. But continue to make rules which aren't attested to. I for one will not adhere to them.

Comment: "Linguistics and the rules of language—grammar—aren't inherently related" — this has to be the most ridiculous statement I have ever seen written about linguistics. What, exactly, do you think linguistics is?

Comment: And for what it's worth, I'm not "making rules"—I'm just observing how language works.

Comment: @nohat Linguistics is, as the OED defines it, “the scientific study of language and its structure. Also: this as a subject of educational study or examination.” Grammar is [defined by the Linguistic Society of America](https://www.linguisticsociety.org/resource/grammar) as  “the collection of principles defining how to put together a sentence.” In other words, linguistics is the study of language—grammar is the whole system and structure of a language.

Comment: @nohat While grammar is undoubtedly a part of the field of linguistics, grammar exists as a separate entity: one need not know morphology or etymology to know grammar. It can be learned independent of linguistics.

Comment: Your logic doesn't follow. Grammar is part of language. Linguistics is the study of language. The study of grammar is a core part of linguistics. That being said, *linguists* are the experts on the scholarly study of grammar. Anyone else is an amateur or a dilettante and any claims they make about grammar are just the opinions of non-experts. Even Garner writes in the preface to GMEU "Discount the advice as you think advisable. No usage critic is infallible—certainly not I."

Comment: @nohat So you believe only linguists can be learned in grammar? That’s unfortunate. There are many non-linguists who have a scholarly knowledge of grammar, hence why I said that grammar is its own entity. I know some very respected teachers that are quite knowledgeable about grammar. To say that only linguists are experts in grammar and everyone else is an amateur is just not true. And those that do not take advice will never attain wisdom. No one in this world is perfect, but does that mean we should never take advice? I think not. But this conversation is going nowhere fast, so let’s end it.

Answer (score 30):

"I" is used when the speaker is the *subject* of the sentence:

> "I kissed Eve."

"Me" is used when the speaker is the *object* of the sentence.

> "Eve kissed me."

Strict grammatical logic says that the same is true when answering questions.

> "Who kissed Eve?"
>
> "I did." or just "I."
>
> **However** in common usage, going back centuries, people frequently use "Me" as a single word answer where "I" would seem logical. It's so common that it can't be considered wrong:
>
> "Me."

..

> "Who did Eve kiss?"
>
> "Me."

By way of illustration; the classic nursery rhyme:

> "Who killed Cock Robin?"
>
> "I," said the Sparrow, with my bow and arrow"

Adding "not" changes nothing.

> "Who kissed Eve?"
>
> "Not I" - agrees with the formal, and still acceptable grammar
>
> "Not me" - agrees with common usage

Both are fine. "Not I" is perhaps a bit ostentatiously literate

> "Who did Eve kiss?"
>
> "Not me." -- *never* "Not I"

Just as with that old chestnut *less* versus *fewer*, it's a one way street. People rarely say *fewer* when *less* is "correct" (except sometimes deliberately, to annoy). People rarely say "Not I" when "Not me" is "correct".

Bottom line: if you always say "Not me", you'll never be wrong. But you miss out on the chance to be extra rigorous in your grammar.

Comment: Irony: *Whom* did Eve kiss. :)

Comment: This answer is excellent.  Both it and Andy's are technically correct.  I try to be careful about this - if you ask me who wants ice cream, I'll probably say "not I".  But it's also true that "not me" is more common; really it doesn't matter too much which you say.

Comment: And not only is it "*Whom* did Eve kiss?" but the answer really is "Me" (and only "Me") because that has to be the accusative case.

Comment: You'll almost never hear "whom did" (although I agree it's correct) from even very rigorous speakers, because the "m" running into the "d" makes it so much harder to pronounce than "who did". Those desperate to use "whom", I think are more likely to say "Eve kissed whom?"

Answer (score 6):

I would say either “I don’t” or “not me.”

I do not know whether “not me” is grammatically correct or not.  If “not me” is acceptable, I guess that “not I” should be the grammatically correct form because “who” in the question is the subject.  But even if so, “not I” sounds like a phrase for the sake of grammatical correctness.

Answer (score 4):

"Not I" is the grammatically correct way to say it (it's a way of rephrasing "I do not.") However, in common parlance (as opposed to formal), you will probably hear "not me" more often, though it's grammatically incorrect (it might be rephrased as "me do not.") As for why it became so common, I couldn't tell you. And yes, in casual conversation, it can sometimes sound awkward and perhaps a bit snooty. But it's not the only case where the grammatically correct way of saying something sounds that way.

TL; DR version: "Not me" probably won't get you funny looks in casual conversation. If you're writing an essay or giving a speech, use the grammatically correct form, "Not I."

Comment: If "Not I" can be construed as rephrasing "I do not [want ice-cream today]" can't "not me" equally be assumed as a rephrasing of "Thank you, but no ice cream for me today"?

Comment: @drewk: I suppose it could. Most grammarians would consider "not me" technically incorrect, probably because in your rephrasing "me" is the object of the preposition. They might argue that "Not I" is acceptable, as well as "Not for me" (assuming the question is phrased such that "not for me" is a semantically correct answer), but not "Not me." But that's just my conjecture; I'm not a professional. Personally though, I think you make a good enough case for "not me"; perhaps I'll use it more to see what others think.

Comment: You assumption that the “incorrect” usage has become more common since a time when everyone spoke “correctly” and used the “correct” usage is false. In fact, it is the opposite. The rule that you must use nominative forms when pronouns are not attached to a verb was invented at around the same time the rule that you can't prepose the objects of prepositions was invented, by analogy with Latin. Before then, nobody thought twice of using accusative forms in this context. “Not me” is the older, and in my opinion, more correct form.

Comment: @nohat: well, not really.  Originally, the nominative really was the default and this remained through at least part of the Middle English period.  Since cases are defunct in English and where they do still exist, are entirely redundant, the default has now switched to the objective form.  The same happened in French as the case system fell apart (in Old French, you could still say, e.g. "ne jo" for "not me/I", but now it is explicitly "non moi" or "pas moi" or "moi non plus" and never *"non je").

Comment: @siride, thanks for the clarification. I think we agree, though, that accusative has been the default for a long time, much longer than grammatical prescription has been a force of any significance.

Comment: Remember The Little Red Hen?  Proof that "Not I" is actually heard.

Answer (score 4):

In traditional English folk songs you will often find lines like:

*...Fair lady, could you fancy I?*

and there's also:

*I care for nobody, no **not I**, if nobody cares for me* (The Miller of Dee)

I'm also reminded of Edmund Blackadder being irritated by an old witch's turn of phrase, and reprimanding her:

"It's *Yes it is* not *That it be*!"
http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b006xxw3

For anyone who doesn't know, this is a BBC comedy programme and the line is obviously done for comic effect, but it stems from the fact that 'it be' was commonly used at one time, and might still be used in certain English dialects.

It's clear that that many kinds of 'incorrect' or non-standard usage have been around for a long time and I don't think it's up to us (we) in the 21st century to tell them they were wrong. The point of language is communication. As long as there's no chance of confusion when using Not I/Not me, it's a matter for personal choice. Let it be!

Answer (score -8):

The correct answer, within confines of economical language, would involve use of the pronoun 'I.' E.g. 'I do' or 'I don't.' 'Not I' would be short for 'It is not I,' but that is not an economical way to answer this question. Still, 'not me' is just wrong because it cannot be short for anything. There is no grammatically correct statement that ends in 'not me.'

The argument that I hear often for the use of 'not me' or other incorrect uses of 'me' is that it has been going on 'for centuries' and 'it is common'; therefore, it should be deemed correct. However, this is an is-ought fallacy. Though it is common practice among those who do not know or care about English grammar; the abuse should not continue. There are generally good reasons for the rules of grammar, and this is a good rule to uphold.

Comment: Why is this a good "rule" to uphold? Why not also the rule about sentences having to have a verb? Why does anything *have* to be short for something else?

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted? It may be aggressively worded, but it makes the important point that "not me" is a sentence fragment that is not short for anything.

Comment: @dotancohen: Because it's wrong. When you respond to a question with a [minor sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sentence_%28linguistics%29&oldid=516950813#Major_and_minor_sentences), you follow the grammatical rules for minor sentences (which require objective case).

Comment: The answer attempts to analyze it as a full sentence with the predicate omitted by [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29). This analysis is wrong because (1) the proposed full sentence differs in meaning, and (2) the full sentence is correctly 'It is not *me*' anyway.

Comment: @PKPK I think this is a mature and thought-out answer. Well done!

Comment: The idea that the way the vast majority of people have spoken for centuries is "wrong" (based on the  misapplication of logic to grammar) is laughable.