# Choosing between 'I' and 'me'

Tags: pronouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is correct, “you and I” or “you and me”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me)
>   [Which one is correct to say: “It's me” or “It's I”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10643/which-one-is-correct-to-say-its-me-or-its-i)
>   [“It is they who lied” or “it is them who lied?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17636/it-is-they-who-lied-or-it-is-them-who-lied)

Which one is grammatically correct: **It was me who called you.**, or **It was I who called you.**? Similarly, which one is correct among these two: **He and me were going to the forest**, or **He and I were going to the forest**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*It was me who called you* and *It was I who called you* are both grammatical in Standard English, with the second being more formal than the first.

*He and I were going to the forest* is also grammatical in Standard English. *He and me were going to the forest* is not, but it may be found in other dialects.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if *"he and me"* were to be a "normal" form in any dialect. I found only two relevant instances in Google Books, and one of those was a trashy "pseudo-grammar" book from 1829. The other came in *"he and me were cronies, though he was ten years older'n me"*, where I think *older'n* makes it clear we're dealing with non-standard phrasing. I think everyone who doesn't say *"He and I"* would say *"Him and me"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: True. I had in mind the more general point that in some dialects 'me' is used in coordination when in subject position: 'Me and the wife was down the pub last night.'

Comment: Haha good example. But even the singular verb *"was"* there doesn't stop us from assuming we're dealing with a native speaker. Whereas if it was (were?!) "corrected" to *"Me was down the pub last night"* we'd take it for granted we were either dealing with a non-native speaker (stereotypically, a native Red Indian), or someone with a serious linguistic handicap.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes, that's why I made a point of saying 'in coordination'.

Answer (score 2):

The simple guide in this situation is "me never does anything". The more complicated version is that *I* is a subject pronoun and *me* is an object pronoun.

*I* (subject) *bit the dog*

*The dog bit me* (object)

On that basis, in your first sentence, *me* can't call you, but *I* can.  In the second, *me* can't be going to the woods, but *I* can.

In real life though, as Barrie correctly says, nobody would bat an an eyelid if you said *It was me who called you*.  This is probably because the 'it' looks like a subject of 'was', making the 'me' appear to be an object. Strictly speaking, the 'was' is not the active verb. That honour goes to 'called'.