# Why "most of them" and not "most of they"?

Tags: prepositions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“It is they who lied” or “it is them who lied?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17636/it-is-they-who-lied-or-it-is-them-who-lied)

Why does "most of..." take an object pronoun, such as *them*, and not *they*? Do all prepositional constructs do this?

Comment: Related: [“It is they who lied” or “it is them who lied?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17636/it-is-they-who-lied-or-it-is-them-who-lied)

Answer (score 5):

It's because when a single pronoun follows a preposition it's in the accusative case.

Comment: Right. In fact, _they_ only occurs as the subject of a tensed clause; for any other use, _them_ is the preferred form.

Comment: @JohnLawler, even when used as a predicate nominative?  I think that *may* be true for spoken English, but for written, it seems a little unusual.

Comment: _It was they at the door_? Naah.

Comment: @thang. When a personal pronoun is the subject predicative of a clause it is normally accusative. For example, _'Who’s making all that noise?’ ‘I’m not sure, but I think it must be **them** again.’_ However, it is in the nominative when it is postmodified, as in _It is **they** who are to blame for this._

Comment: That's a pet peeve **of mine**.