# What to use SHE or HER?

Tags: pronouns

So I was having this conversation with a friend about my ex and she asked me, "Who broke up?"

I said, "She"

My friend was like, "It should be her and not "she"?

Could someone please help me out on this?

Comment: Your choices are "She did" or "Her". You can't use a mix of both. For details, see [this excellent answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/4655/300) on the question I'm closing this one as a duplicate of.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Would there be anything wrong with "She [did]", with the "did" elided? But I would accept it would probably be more idiomatic to say "her".

Comment: @WS2 if you elided the "did", you'd be left with just the "she", so that's one thing for starters that would be wrong with that.

Comment: @RegDwigнt It seems hardly worth arguing about. I agree that "she" does not sound idiomatic, but I don't really see what's wrong with it.