# Correct answer for the following question

Tags: american-english

Question: Who broke the jar?

Answer 1: "I"
Answer 2: "Me"

Which answer is correct?

Comment: In real, spoken English, "Me." In the made-up rules of grammar books that think English should work like the classical languages, "I". To make everyone happy, you can say "I broke it."

Comment: In all varieties of English, real or fake, spoken or written, the answer is "me", and I don't know of a single grammar book that would say otherwise. https://english.stackexchange.com/a/4655/300

Comment: The _correct_ answer is "I did", though in colloquial speech many people would say "Me".

Comment: Thank you, guys!