# Should it be Me or I in this sentence

Tags: grammar, british-english, pronouns

'Healthy Body and Me' or 'Healthy Body and I' which one is correct ? It's actually a name of the blog so I appreciate for your advice and also if you could explain why. Thanks

Comment: 'I and my Shadow'??? Neither sounds too wonderful, to be honest, but 'Healthy Body and I' sounds awful.

Comment: This is not a sentence.

Comment: The BBC had a programme, in a series called "Body Image", called "My Big Breasts and Me".

Comment: Also, a review of shoes designed for comfort said "they get my feet and me through the day".

Comment: Your answer is [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/4655/300).

Comment: That said, it's a very poor title to begin with. Very clumsy and awkward. Very necrophilic. I suggest you scrap it entirely and think of something that sounds nice and not gross.

Comment: At the pearly gates of Heaven St Peter hears a knocking. He asks, "Who's there?" and a voice answers, "It is I." and St. Peter says, "Oh, another English teacher!"

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the phrase you're shortening. As an object, you're saying "This blog will discuss topics about healthy body and me." As the subject, you're saying, "Healthy Body and I will be the focus of this blog."

The latter would be grammatically correct, but as a title for a blog, it just doesn't "sound" right for the casual readers these days. If you want my opinion for a non-nerdist blog, go with "Healthy Body and Me."

Comment: Thank you guys, I used certain key words in this name for SEO, and also many good names are already taken. So that what I got .